# How to add a new Text Editor template?

Tags: customization, text-editor

In Blender's built-in *Text Editor*, there's a *Templates* menu at the bottom with a bunch of pre-built templates for scripting addons. However, I have created a few new templates myself that I use frequently. Is there any way for me to add my templates to this menu?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `[version_number]/scripts` subfolder of your Blender installation, or in any additional path(s) for scripts you've set in User Preferences, there's a folder `templates_py` (and one for osl too). Just put the templates there; in the menu, each `_` in the file name will be converted into a space and each beginning letter of a word capitalized.

Comment: *Very trivial* note ;), the beginning letter gets uppercased and also the first letter that comes after a number.

Comment: Ha! Never realized the number-prefix bits :D

Answer (score 3):

The *Templates > Python* menu item is getting quite long now.

#### 1. x_templates

[repository link](https://github.com/zeffii/x_templates)

Here's an add-on that adds an extra sub-menu called *x_templates* to the Templates list, and dynamically creates sub-sub-menus

[image]

To make menu items all you have to do is add folders and files into the add-on's folder. The add-on does the rest.

[image]

Each of these folders (except the `__pycache__` folder) contains some number of .py files.

---

#### 2. Using self.path_menu

Add your own folder along side the existing folders.

[image]

`self.path_menu(fullpath, "text.open", {"internal: True})`

like this

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Extra Templates",
    "author": "you",
    "version": (0, 1),
    "blender": (2, 7, 6),
    "category": "Text Editor"
}

import bpy

class TEXT_MT_templates_my_py(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = "My Python"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_MT_custom_py_menu"

    def draw(self, context):
        self.path_menu(
            bpy.utils.script_paths("templates_my_py"),
            "text.open",
            {"internal": True},
        )

def draw_item(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    layout.menu(TEXT_MT_templates_my_py.bl_idname)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.TEXT_MT_templates.append(draw_item)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.TEXT_MT_templates.remove(draw_item)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```